# Convert MM:SS to HH:MM:SS (cast to time), SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am attempting to convert a columns data from MM:SS to time [HH:MM:SS.NNNNNNN] so that i can aggregate the field in my cube/aggregate dimension. As the photo below [source] depicts, the data was landed into my database in the data type/format of MM:SS (varchar).

[image: SOURCE]

[image: LAND_TABLE]

I attempted to parse out the minutes and seconds; cast the columns into datatype int; and write a case to calculate hours.

From this, i then wrote a case to get the data into the time datatype [Case Column photo]. However, when i went to cast the new calculated field as time, it came up with an error message.

[image: Case Column]

How would i go about doing this?

```js
SELECT CAST ( HRS AS VARCHAR(2) ) + ':' + CAST ( MN AS VARCHAR(2) ) + ':' + CAST (SEC  AS VARCHAR(2)) + '.' + '0000000' AS TOI
FROM  (  
    SELECT CASE
    WHEN  CAST ( PARSENAME ( REPLACE ( TOI, ':', '.'), 2 ) AS INT) > 60 AND  CAST ( PARSENAME ( REPLACE ( TOI, ':', '.'), 2 ) AS INT) < 120 THEN '01'
    WHEN  CAST ( PARSENAME ( REPLACE ( TOI, ':', '.'), 2 ) AS INT) > 120 THEN '02'
    WHEN  CAST ( PARSENAME ( REPLACE ( TOI, ':', '.'), 2 ) AS INT) < 60  THEN '00'
    ELSE '00'
     END AS HRS
     , CASE 
      WHEN CAST ( PARSENAME ( REPLACE ( TOI, ':', '.'), 2 ) AS INT) > 60 THEN CONCAT(0, PARSENAME ( REPLACE ( TOI, ':', '.'), 2 ) - 60)
      WHEN CAST ( PARSENAME ( REPLACE ( TOI, ':', '.'), 2 ) AS INT) > 60 THEN PARSENAME ( REPLACE ( TOI, ':', '.'), 2 )
      ELSE PARSENAME ( REPLACE ( TOI, ':', '.'), 2 )
       END AS MN
     , PARSENAME ( REPLACE ( TOI, ':', '.'), 1 ) AS SEC
    FROM LAND_HOME_GOALIES
   ) S;
```

Comment: My general feeling is to not store time by itself, or if you do then at least include hours, minutes, and seconds together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In real life '`61:15`' is not considered to be valid `MM:SS` data like you are saying.But in case if it true somehow then,

```
declare @table table(TOI varchar(10))
insert into @table values ('241:15')
,('61:15'),('40:36')

select TOI as OLdTOI,right(('00'+ cast(([Min]/60) as varchar)),2)
+':'+right('00'+cast([Min]-([Min]/60)*60 as varchar) , 2)
+':'+ right('00'+Sec,2) NewTOI
 from
(
select TOI, substring(TOI,0,charindex(':',TOI)) [Min]
,substring(TOI,charindex(':',TOI)+1,len(TOI)) Sec
from @table
)t4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the value to seconds:

```
select convert(int, left(toi, 2)) * 60 + convert(int, right(toi, 2))
```

You can then sum to seconds, and convert back to hours by dividing by 3600.  Or convert to a time value by using `dateadd()` to a zero time.

Comment: Thanks! One additional thing.  For some rows, the minutes only have one value.  For example, one value in TOI may be "8:04" so when I run the code i get "message 245.... conversion failed when converting the varchar value '8:' to data type int".  The code works for the rows that have 2 min values but not one.  Is there a way that i can account for when the column values only have one minute value (ie M:SS)? I have no way of changing the source data as it is scraped & landed from a NHL game boxscore table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it wise to store temporal data as stings, it always results in complications.  Allowing for hours:minutes:seconds in that string (amend to suit):

```
select 
      TOItime
from LAND_HOME_GOALIES
cross apply (select replace(TOI,':','.')) ca1 (xTOI)
cross apply (
    select coalesce(try_cast(parsename(ca1.xTOI,3) as int),0) * 3600
         + coalesce(try_cast(parsename(ca1.xTOI,2) as int),0) * 60
         + coalesce(try_cast(parsename(ca1.xTOI,1) as int),0)
            ) ca2 (secs)
cross apply (select try_cast(dateadd(second,ca2.secs,0) as time)) ca3 (TOItime)
```

I assume you can use try_cast if not use cast but there could be errors in conversion to int.

### ----

EDIT

To demonstrate the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cfd9/1) will show it converts the original strings to time with no impact at all on number of rows:

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE LAND_HOME_GOALIES
    ([TOI] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO LAND_HOME_GOALIES
    ([TOI])
VALUES
    ('40:36'),
    ('19:24'),
    ('61:15'),
    ('60:00'),
    ('58.47'),
    ('59:54'),
    ('64:49')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
      TOI, ca1.xTOI, ca2.secs, ca3.TOItime
from LAND_HOME_GOALIES
cross apply (select replace(TOI,':','.')) ca1 (xTOI)
cross apply (
    select coalesce(try_cast(parsename(ca1.xTOI,3) as int),0) * 3600
         + coalesce(try_cast(parsename(ca1.xTOI,2) as int),0) * 60
         + coalesce(try_cast(parsename(ca1.xTOI,1) as int),0)
            ) ca2 (secs)
cross apply (select try_cast(dateadd(second,ca2.secs,0) as time)) ca3 (TOItime)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cfd9/1/0)**:

```
|   TOI |  xTOI | secs |          TOItime |
|-------|-------|------|------------------|
| 40:36 | 40.36 | 2436 | 00:40:36.0000000 |
| 19:24 | 19.24 | 1164 | 00:19:24.0000000 |
| 61:15 | 61.15 | 3675 | 01:01:15.0000000 |
| 60:00 | 60.00 | 3600 | 01:00:00.0000000 |
| 58.47 | 58.47 | 3527 | 00:58:47.0000000 |
| 59:54 | 59.54 | 3594 | 00:59:54.0000000 |
| 64:49 | 64.49 | 3889 | 01:04:49.0000000 |
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just a quick addendum, this query for TOI time you created seems to duplicate every row. so instead of say 400 original rows from the land table there will now be 800 rows in the stage table (from running this code). Is this there a way around this?

Comment: There is nothing in that query that would multiply row. Each `cross apply` adds one column so you do get 3 new columns.

Comment: demonstration of how the query adds columns, but NOT rows, has been added available online also at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cfd9/1